# I need to zero out one of the color channels in an NSImage, whats the right way to do this?

Tags: cocoa, colors, nsimage

I want to achieve the same result as if I were in photoshop and turned off one of the channels. I was about to try to loop through every pixel changing colors. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Core Image's Color Matrix filter. [The array of vectors can be bewildering, but it's very powerful.](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-02-18/how-to-convert-an-alpha-channel-to-a-mask) In your case, you'll want to set the vector for the channel you want to turn off to all-zeroes.

Obviously, this will only work for RGB images, since Core Image only works for RGB images. You can make it work for gray images (turn off R, G, and B to turn off the K channel), but not for CMYK.

Comment: I haven't used core image filters before, how do you apply a filter?

Comment: Tell the filter to apply itself. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/

Comment: after I've applied the filter how do I convert a CIImage back to an NSImage

Comment: Revision to my previous comment: I was thinking of CIKernel. For the filter, you set its input image, then any input parameters, then get its output image.

Comment: rennat: Create an NSCIImageRep with the CIImage, create an NSImage, and put the NSCIImageRep in the NSImage. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCIImageRep_Class/