# How can I remove remove one color channel from an NSimage?

Tags: objective-c, nsimage

As the title says: how can I remove remove one color channel from an NSimage?

Basically I want to achieve a result equivalent to opening an image in Photoshop and deleting all the info in the red channel.

I'm guessing there's maybe a way to do this with core image filters but I can't find the right one.

Comment: Did you look at creating your own filter? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html

Comment: take a look at : [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Comment: See here: [I need to zero out one of the color channels in an NSImage, whats the right way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230145/i-need-to-zero-out-one-of-the-color-channels-in-an-nsimage-whats-the-right-way)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to zero out one of the color channels in an NSImage, whats the right way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230145/i-need-to-zero-out-one-of-the-color-channels-in-an-nsimage-whats-the-right-way)